# Can't get spinner selected item inside an AlertDialog Android

Tags: android, spinner, android-alertdialog

I would like to get the value of the item selected in a spinner inside an AlertDialog, after pressing the PositiveButton.
My function:

```
public void open_and_get() {
    View dialog_filtri=View.inflate(this,R.layout.finestra_filtri,null);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Filtra per");
    builder.setView(dialog_filtri);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Filtra",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
//All the spinners are inside a Linear layout, so i would like to get it and slide inside his spinner child to get them parameters.
           View view=(View) LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.finestra_filtri,null);
           LinearLayout l= (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.linear_con_filtri);
           String[] parametri=new String[l.getChildCount()];
           int i;

           for(i=0;i<l.getChildCount();i++) {
                if(l.getChildAt(i) instanceof Spinner) {
                    Spinner temp=(Spinner)l.getChildAt(i);
                    parametri[i]=temp.getSelectedItem().toString();
                }
           }
           Log.d(TAG,""+parametri[0]+"\n"+parametri[1]);
       }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancella",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
```

The problem is that i can get only the default values of the spinner, maybe because i am not referring to the correct spinner but to a new one.

Comment: Yes, it is because your are inflating a new layout. Create a custom dialog and pass the selected item in its constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this code line,

```
View view=(View) LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.finestra_filtri,null);
```

You are inflating new view of Alert Dialog and referencing to it, not a shown one,

So Remove code line,

```
View view=(View) LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.finestra_filtri,null);
```

and change line,

```
LinearLayout l= (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.linear_con_filtri);
```

with

```
LinearLayout l= (LinearLayout) dialog_filtri.findViewById(R.id.linear_con_filtri);
```